# How can I set an attribute of node in XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfOffice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Offices>
<Office>
<OfficeId>5</OfficeId>
<OfficeName>NewOne1</OfficeName>
<City>Mehsana1</City>
<Country>India1</Country>
</Office>
<Office>
<OfficeId>8</OfficeId>
<OfficeName>NewOne</OfficeName>
<City>Mehsna1</City>
<Country>Country</Country>
</Office>
<Office>
<OfficeId>9</OfficeId>
<OfficeName>Nataraj</OfficeName>
<City>Mehsana</City>
<Country>India</Country>
</Office>
<Office>
<OfficeId>10</OfficeId>
<OfficeName>Nere1</OfficeName>
<City>Nere1</City>
<Country>USA1</Country>
</Office>
<Office>
<OfficeId>11</OfficeId>
<OfficeName>Nataraj</OfficeName>
<City>Mehsana</City>
<Country>India</Country>
</Office>
<Office>
<OfficeId>15</OfficeId>
<OfficeName>Nere1</OfficeName>
<City>Nere1</City>
<Country>USA1</Country>
</Office>
</Offices>
</ArrayOfOffice>
```

Now I want to add an attribute in `<Offices>` Tag like `<Offices Multi="Y">..........</Offices>`

How can I set this `Multi="Y"` in `Offices` Node using C#? Do I have to edit the xml File and save back to that xml file?

Thanks.

Comment: Be more specific, to which element do you want to set attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to load the XML file, add the `Multi` attribute to the `Offices` tag and save it back:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var offices = doc.Element("ArrayOfOffice").Element("Offices");
offices.Add(new XAttribute("Multi", "Y"));
doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Or with a [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) if you are using an older version than .NET 3.5:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");
var offices = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Offices");
var multi = doc.CreateAttribute("Multi");
multi.Value = "Y";
offices.Attributes.Append(multi);
doc.Save("test.xml");
```